# Applet not seeing javascript methods every time

Tags: javascript, browser, applet

I have an applet that does extensive communication with javascript and the browser. Now, I've stuck a JSObject call in the init method of the applet to notify the browser that the applet is there and good to go, but I've noticed something strange. **Occasionally, when making a javascript call from an applet in its init() method, the call fails as if the javascript method does not exist.** The applet is not loaded until $(document).ready(), so I do not see how this is possible.

Does anyone have any insight or experience with failing applet/javascript communication?

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace if one is generated, Do you know if its the Applet-> JS call for certain thats failing or if its a javascript error once the function is called?  Can you post your method for calling the js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you REALLY don't have any edge cases where the JavaScript call is made before the document ready. You're probably missing some obscure timing issue.